# Python: Scipy's curve_fit for NxM arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting

Usually I use Scipy.optimize.curve_fit to fit custom functions to data.
Data in this case was always a 1 dimensional array.

Is there a similiar function for a two dimensional array?

So, for example, I have a 10x10 numpy array. Then I have a function that does some stuff and creates a 10x10 numpy array, and I want to fit the function, so that the resulting 10x10 array has the best fit to the input array.

Maybe an example is better :)

```
data = pyfits.getdata('data.fits')  #fits is an image format, this gives me a NxM numpy array
mod1 = pyfits.getdata('mod1.fits')
mod2 = pyfits.getdata('mod2.fits')    
mod3 = pyfits.getdata('mod3.fits')

mod1_1D = numpy.ravel(mod1)
mod2_1D = numpy.ravel(mod2)    
mod3_1D = numpy.ravel(mod3)
def dostuff(a,b):    #originaly this is a function for 2D arrays
    newdata = (mod1_1D*12)+(mod2_1D)**a - mod3_1D/b
    return newdata
```

Now a and b should be fitted, so that newdata is as close as possible to data.

What I got so far:

```
data1D = numpy.ravel(data)
data_X = numpy.arange(data1D.size)
fit = curve_fit(dostuff,data_X,data1D)
```

But print fit only gives me

```
(array([ 1.]), inf)
```

I do have some nans in the arrays, maybe thats a problem?

Comment: Do you have some example data?

Comment: Have you tried to flatten the data and the output of the function? This should make them both 1-dimensional to work with curve_fit.

Comment: I'm not sure that this could work. In my case, the NxM numpy array represents an image. If I flatten it, then at the edges it might have very sharp jumps in a value, which might be bad for fitting.

Comment: @Pythoneer That is not a problem if the function also creates a 2D image that is flattened. It will contain the same jumps... ah I think I start to see the problem...

Comment: An example is always better... even better is an example that does not depend on external data: [minimal, complete, and verifyable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `nan` in the array *may* cause problems because I don't think `curve_fit` accounts for them when it computes its internal cost function. The way you specify `dostuff` *certainly* causes problems. `curve_fit` tries to fit `y = f(x, a, b, ...)` and uses the first parameter as the independent variable. You'll need to specify `def dostuff(x, a, b)` even if you don't need to use `x`.

Answer (score 2):

The goal is to express the 2D function as a 1D function: `g(x, y, ...) --> f(xy, ...)`

Converting the coordinate pair `(x, y)` into a single number `xy` may seem tricky at first. But it's actually quite simple. Just enumerate all data points and you have a single number that uniquely defines each coordinate pair. The fitted function simply has to reconstruct the original coordinates, do it's calculations and return the result.

Example that fits a 2D linear gradient in a 20x10 image:

```
import scipy as sp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n, m = 10, 20

# noisy example data
x = np.arange(m).reshape(1, m)
y = np.arange(n).reshape(n, 1)
z = x + y * 2 + np.random.randn(n, m) * 3

def f(xy, a, b):
    i = xy // m  # reconstruct y coordinates
    j = xy % m  # reconstruct x coordinates
    out = i * a + j * b
    return out

xy = np.arange(z.size)  # 0 is the top left pixel and 199 is the top right pixel
res = sp.optimize.curve_fit(f, xy, np.ravel(z))

z_est = f(xy, *res[0])
z_est2d = z_est.reshape(n, m)


plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
plt.plot(np.ravel(z), label='original')
plt.plot(z_est, label='fitted')
plt.legend()

plt.subplot(2, 2, 3)
plt.imshow(z)
plt.xlabel('original')

plt.subplot(2, 2, 4)
plt.imshow(z_est2d)
plt.xlabel('fitted')
```

[image]

Comment: That looks really promising, I will try it out. Thx!

Comment: Hmmm, I'm having trouble understanding this separation of the coordinates for my function. Lets say I have a function which depends on variables a and b, and the actual calculation is something like (array  * a)**b. How do I do this for each coordinate separately? Is it still (i * a)**b + (j * a)**b?

Comment: What I got so far is, I have my input data as an array, and I transformed it into 1D using np.ravel(). I need a second array, lets say B in my calculation, which I also created a 1D version. Now I have def dostuff(a,b) which does ((12 * B1D) * a)**b and returns it. But If I let the fit do its thing with fit = curve_fit(dostuff,data_X,data1D) it only returns (array([ 1.]), inf).

Comment: It looks like the operation (*a)**b is applied to each element of the array, independent of the element's position. In that case you don't have to worry about coordinates or 1D/2D... But what is `array`?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [`symfit`](http://symfit.readthedocs.io) for this, I wrote that to take care of all of the magic for you automatically.

In [`symfit`](http://symfit.readthedocs.io) you would just write the equation pretty much as you would on paper, and then you can run the fit.

I would do something like this:

```
from symfit import parameters, variables, Fit

# Assuming all this data is in the form of NxM arrays
data = pyfits.getdata('data.fits')
mod1 = pyfits.getdata('mod1.fits')
mod2 = pyfits.getdata('mod2.fits')    
mod3 = pyfits.getdata('mod3.fits')

a, b = parameters('a, b')
x, y, z, u = variables('x, y, z, u')
model = {u: (x * 12) + y**a - z / b}

fit = Fit(model, x=mod1, y=mod2, z=mod3, u=data)
fit_result = fit.execute()
print(fit_result)
```

Unfortunatelly I have not yet included examples of the kind you need in the docs yet, but if you just look at the [docs](http://symfit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html) I think you can figure it out in case this doesn't work out of the box.