# Python: scipy curve_fit for 2d array (an image)

Tags: python, image-processing, scipy, curve-fitting

I try to use the explanation (first answer) from this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43202089/python-scipys-curve-fit-for-nxm-arrays), to create an lsq fit for a 2D function with 6 parameters, which finds the optimized parameters from the data (an image, so a 2D array). It does so by enumerating the 2D array into a 1D array, and the example given works fine.

I get an

```
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

for the code below. It might be a trivial error I get, as I am still getting familiar with Python, but I cannot seem to understand why my code is not working, whereas the example in the topic does. Does someone see my mistake?

```
def lsqFitFunc(img):
        
    def fitFullFunc(xy, amplitude, sigmaY, shiftX, shiftY, background, sigmaX):
        x = xy % imspx.shape[1] # reconstruct x coordinates [0..size]
        y = xy // imspx.shape[1] 
        return background + amplitude * math.exp(-sigmaY * ( y - shiftY )**2  ) * ( (1/2) * ( 1+math.erf( ( x - shiftX )/(13*sigmaX/math.sqrt(2)) ) ) )    

    xy = np.arange(img.size)  # 0 is the top left pixel and 199 is the top right pixel    
    res = sp.optimize.curve_fit(fitFullFunc, xy, np.ravel(img))        
    return res
```

I am using the following input for this function:

```
img = np.array([[223, 228, 231, 233, 236, 241, 244, 247, 251, 250, 253, 255, 255,
        254, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
       [205, 209, 214, 219, 220, 224, 229, 235, 240, 242, 246, 251, 254,
        254, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
       [183, 188, 193, 196, 200, 205, 210, 217, 223, 229, 232, 241, 244,
        251, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 254, 255, 255],
       [166, 169, 172, 176, 181, 184, 191, 196, 202, 209, 216, 226, 234,
        243, 250, 255, 254, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
       [152, 156, 157, 161, 164, 167, 172, 178, 186, 193, 203, 212, 224,
        234, 245, 252, 252, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
       [145, 146, 147, 149, 152, 156, 158, 163, 171, 179, 191, 202, 217,
        228, 238, 249, 251, 254, 253, 255, 255, 255],
       [140, 142, 142, 144, 145, 148, 150, 156, 163, 174, 185, 197, 212,
        223, 235, 245, 251, 254, 255, 255, 255, 255],
       [140, 141, 142, 144, 144, 148, 150, 157, 165, 174, 188, 198, 213,
        226, 239, 246, 251, 254, 254, 253, 255, 254],
       [142, 144, 145, 146, 148, 153, 156, 162, 172, 181, 194, 206, 220,
        230, 241, 250, 252, 255, 253, 255, 255, 255],
       [147, 149, 151, 153, 156, 161, 167, 173, 184, 195, 206, 217, 230,
        237, 247, 253, 255, 255, 254, 255, 254, 253],
       [155, 158, 160, 165, 168, 176, 180, 190, 200, 208, 220, 229, 240,
        246, 253, 255, 255, 255, 254, 255, 254, 255],
       [168, 171, 176, 179, 187, 192, 198, 206, 214, 222, 232, 239, 248,
        255, 254, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
       [186, 188, 196, 201, 205, 209, 214, 223, 230, 236, 243, 249, 251,
        255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255]])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [scipy curve\_fit doesn't like math module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48226089/scipy-curve-fit-doesnt-like-math-module)

Answer (score 1):

Together with a colleague, we found the math functions (exp, erf) do not accept arrays, which gave the error. The numpy and scipy functions for those functions shall be used:

```
return background + amplitude * np.exp(-sigmaY * ( y - shiftY )**2  ) * ( (1/2) * ( 1+ sp.special.erf( ( x - shiftX )/(13*sigmaX/math.sqrt(2)) ) ) )
```

Comment: If you fixed your issue, could you accept your own answer?

Comment: I will do, can do so after 48h